# HTTP call to Firebase Realtime Database

Tags: json, http, ionic-framework, firebase-realtime-database, angular-promise

I'm begineer level and using simple HTTP call in IONIC 3 to the firebase to retrieve data. Everything works well, but when I try to add image URL into data. The output is raw URL link instead of display image.

How should i call the image URL in IONIC 3 and link to unique item of data?

Thanks.

Output:
[image]

Here is Firebase raw data:
[image]

Here is Ionic Source Code:
(API service)

```
export class apiService {
     private baseUrl = 'https://mymenu-d4110.firebaseio.com';
    constructor(private http:Http){}

getMenu(){
    return new Promise(resolve =>{
        this.http.get(`${this.baseUrl}/menu-data/food.json`)
        .subscribe(res => resolve(res.json()));
    });
}
```

(Function code):

```
 ionViewDidLoad() {

    this.apiService.getMenu().then(data=>
    this.food = data);

  }
```

(HTML Code)

```
 <ion-item>
    <ion-label>Name</ion-label>
    <ion-label>Description</ion-label>
    <ion-label>Price</ion-label>
    <ion-label>Photo</ion-label>
  </ion-item>

  <ion-item *ngFor="let item of food">
    <ion-label>{{item.name}} </ion-label>
    <ion-label>{{item.description}} </ion-label>
    <ion-label>{{item.chinese}} </ion-label>
    <ion-label>{{item.photo}} </ion-label>
  </ion-item>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using the  tag. Swap

```
<ion-label>{{item.photo}} </ion-label>
```

with

```
<ion-img width="80" height="80" [src]="item.photo"></ion-img>
```

You can read more about it here: https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/components/img/Img/

Edit:
On a side note, based on the docs, you should use a `<img>` tag instead of `<ion-img>` if your image is not in a virtual-scoll